# local php.ini values not being found by apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am working on a server that is running apache in CGI mode, meaning that I cannot use an `.htaccess` file to change the php error reporting settings, which are turned off by default (no logging or displaying of errors) , I created a php.ini file with the following commands in order to enable it:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

I created a file that calls `phpinfo()` in order to check if it was working correctly, and it shows the file set in the `PHPRC` variable. however, error_reporting and display_errors still state *No Value* on the phpinfo page.

How can I correct this and get error reporting (either displayed or logged to a file somewhere) working correctly?

Comment: Which php.ini file you're editing? Where do you put it?

Comment: Did you restart apache after the changes of php.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd try to make sure it's loading the php.ini you created by checking the "loaded configuration file" on the phpinfo() output.

If it's not loading the one you want, you can specify its location. Take a look at this link: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-debian-etch-p2

Hope this helps.